# apt source pulling old packages

Tags: apt, compiling, vpn, source, ipsec

I am trying to pull the source files from an apt repo

`sudo apt source strongswan`

This pulls down version 5.6.2. However on the [ubuntu 20.04 focal page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/strongswan), it shows 5.8.2-1. Why is this version not being pulled? How can I get this version to be sourced instead?

Here is `apt policy strongswan`

```
strongswan:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.8.2-1ubuntu3.4
  Version table:
     5.8.2-1ubuntu3.4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.8.2-1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Confirmed I am using 20.04. This system was 18.04 but I upgraded to 20.04.

```
# cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: you are not using 20.04? your deb-src does not point to focal? I can't think of anything else :D so please provide the details about those two in the question ;-)

Comment: I updated my post with version and apt policy.

Comment: That apt-policy looks like mine. But I don't have any `deb-src` lines in my sources list. Do yours point to `focal`? 5.6.2 is the `bionic` version.

Comment: That was it! my source.list still had old bionic locations in it. Did you want to post the solution? Or may I?

Comment: Go ahead, you got this!

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.
Problem was my /etc/apt/source.list still had old entries for bionic sources. As I mentioned in my post, I upgraded this system to 20.04 a while back. I guess the upgrade never updated the source.list file.

Simple fix:

```
sudo sed -i 's/bionic/focal/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt source strongswan
```

Now 5.8.2 is being downloaded properly.

Thanks to @Organic Marble and @Rinzwind for the help!